# I'm getting an error when using RestSharp DigestAuthenticator

Tags: asp.net-core, restsharp

So I have a .net core API that's trying to use RestSharp(which I'm fairly new to) to call another API. This other API apparently requires Digest based authentication to access, so I went ahead and tried using the DigestAuthenticator class provided by RestSharp. However, the result was an error saying Header not found : Digest Realm. Image of error below.

[RestSharp DigestAuthenticator Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ2yD.png)

So, I'm assuming that I would need to add a header for digest auth in my request. But, how would I go about doing that?

Below is what I've done so far,

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri("http://ip_address:port/otherApi");
client.Authenticator = new DigestAuthenticator("myusername", "mypassword");
request.Method = Method.POST;

//not sure how to add header for digest auth
//request.AddHeader("")
request.AddParameter("application/xml", xmlString, ParameterType.RequestBody);

client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

return Ok(response.Content);
```

Comment: You can try the steps in this article, it might help: https://sourceexample.com/i-tried-digest-authentication-with-restsharp-41c61/

Comment: @Chaodeng Unfortunately, it seems the results are still the same.

Comment: Use `request.AddHeader`